# Adding text box on clicking in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I was working on a project in qt. I want to add a text box and label after triggering of button. I am working in QWidgets. How can I do that. Please help me to do the task. I searched and got how to add the text in text on clicking of button but what I want is to add textbox itself on clicking of button. After Triggring of menu item text box should be added. But was unable to find that how to do that.

Comment: QML or QWidget?  What have you tried so far? This question will be closed quickly unless you add more details: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am using QWidgets. Edited the question too.

Comment: Two ways: either have the text box there all the time, just show/hide it as needed, or add new widgets to the layout when needed. I'd try the first approach first. Both need to be implemented in C++ code, if that is what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

[image]

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    this->setCentralWidget(new QWidget());
    m_layout = new QHBoxLayout();
    this->centralWidget()->setLayout(m_layout);

    QPushButton * button = new QPushButton("Add another Button");
    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_buttonClick()));
    m_layout->addWidget(button);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_buttonClick()
{
    m_layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("New Button"));
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QHBoxLayout>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public slots:
    void on_buttonClick();
private:
    QHBoxLayout * m_layout;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Hope that helps.